# MySql Null DateTime and MS.net are not playing nice

Tags: mysql, .net, datetime, linq-to-sql, null

Heres the issue.

I have a table(mySQL) that contains dates and some of them are null.
I know that I can use DateTime? or Nullable to allow nulls, but I'm not sure where to set it.

What I've tried:

I built the class in the dblm. The date propery has the following attributes set:

```
Nullable : True
Server Data Type : DateTime
Type : NUllable<DateTime>
```

These settings allow my code to be built.
When I debug it a get this exception thrown:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

If I try to with these attributes:

```
Nullable : True
Server Data Type : NUllable<DateTime>
Type : NUllable<DateTime>
```

I get the same exception as above.

Other ways that did not work:

```
Nullable : True
Server Data Type : DateTime?
Type : NUllable<DateTime>

Nullable : True
Server Data Type : DateTime?
Type : DateTime?
```

I'm using .net's 3.5 Framework

Thanks

Comment: Show the code where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a [problem](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/topic47934.aspx) with mysql's ADO.NET driver, where it was not playing nice with nulled date/time fields at all.

Even IsDBNull was throwing exception on a field with null date/time.

It may be still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - 
It turned out to be an issue with the connection string to connect to the mySQL DB.

Also I didn't know that it was possible to drop a table into the DBML using the Server Explorer.  All I needed to do was connect to the database then drop the table onto the DBML.